# How to show the direction of highlighted path in graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to show the direction of `FindHamiltonianPath` on the `Graph`.

```
g = Graph[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "SkeletonGraph"], VertexLabels -> "Name"];

path = FindHamiltonianPath[g]

(*{4, 15, 10, 9, 14, 1, 16, 8, 12, 6, 20, 18, 13, 17, 19, 3, 7, 11, 5, 2} *)

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[path]]
```

[image]

Now how can I show the direction of the path on the graph which starts at 4 and ends at 2 (draw the path as an arrows).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add additional graphics (arrow) using Epilog or Prolog:

Ex1:

```
HighlightGraph[g, path, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.05], 
   Arrow /@ Partition[GraphEmbedding[g][[path]], 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

Ex2:

```
HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[path], 
 Prolog -> {Orange, Thickness[.005], Arrowheads[Table[.04, 10]], 
   Arrow[BSplineCurve[GraphEmbedding[g][[path]], SplineDegree -> 2]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is a V9 answer:

```
g = DirectedGraph[GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"], 
                  VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeStyle -> White];
HighlightGraph[g, FindHamiltonianCycle[g][[1]] // Most]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g = DirectedGraph[GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
HighlightGraph[g, FindHamiltonianCycle[g][[1]] // Most]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
g = Graph[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "SkeletonGraph"], VertexLabels -> "Name"];
path = FindHamiltonianPath[g]
```

> {13, 18, 10, 15, 4, 20, 6, 2, 5, 19, 3, 7, 11, 12, 8, 16, 1, 14, 9, 17}

```
HighlightGraph[g, { EdgeList@PathGraph[path], path}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[If[OrderedQ[#2], {0, .05}, {-.05, 0}]],
  Arrow @ #} &)]
```

[image]

To make the highlighted edges curved use

```
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[If[OrderedQ[#2], {0, .05}, {-.05, 0}]],
       Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> (-Order@@#2 )/2 }][##]]} &)
```

[image]

To have both the original and arrow versions of highlighted edges, use

```
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[If[OrderedQ[#2], {0, .05}, {-.05, 0}]],
   Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> (-Order@@#2 )/2 }][##]], 
  Thin, Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]], Line@#} &)
```

[image]